# Calling captureOutput in IBAction

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, avfoundation, avcaptureoutput

I'd like to create an app, which after clicking `IBAction` button should display current frame from live camera on `UIImageView`.
Using this method: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1702/_index.html
I'd like to create fuction in `IBAction` fuction. This one exactly:

```
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput
```

Unfortunately after dozen of attempts I can't do it.

> Summarizing: How to create a function (void), which contains image in
>   `UIImage` form and save it to object in storyboard?

I'd be grateful for any help.
Regards.

Comment: Why would you save to storyboard? Storyboard is a representation of "V" - View in MVC pattern. You should not "save" anything in view.

Comment: @Vive 
Okay, if you do not give what I could do to save a UIImage

Answer (score 0):

Use this method to capture still images from `AVCaptureSession`  where `stillImageOutput` is `AVCaptureStillImageOutput`:

```
[stillImageOutput captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection:videoConnection completionHandler: ^(CMSampleBufferRef imageSampleBuffer, NSError *error)
{
    CVImageBufferRef imageBuffer =CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(imageSampleBuffer);
    CIImage *ciImage = [CIImage imageWithCVPixelBuffer:imageBuffer];
    CIContext *temporaryContext = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];
    CGImageRef videoImage =[temporaryContext
        createCGImage:ciImage
        fromRect:CGRectMake(
            0, 0,
            CVPixelBufferGetWidth(imageBuffer),
            CVPixelBufferGetHeight(imageBuffer)
        )];
    UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:videoImage];
    self.imageView.image = image;
}
```